# While Loop does not complete its execution in the stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

I am writing a store procedure that accepts two inputs such as startingNumber=A00001 and EndingNumber=A00049  which should generate number as follows and insert in the table:

```
A00001
A00002
A00003
A00004
.
.
.
A00049
```

But the stored procedure is not working as desired and it keeps on executing and does not get completed. Can anyone help me to figure out where it went wrong and how to solve it. Is it the appropriate approach for doing such things and i would be more happy if someone could give me some other alternative solutions.
Here is the stored procedure that i have written:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertNumbers]
@StartingNumber nvarchar(25),
@EndingNumber nvarchar(25)
AS
Declare @StartIndex int 
Declare @EndIndex int 
Declare @Series varchar(5) 
Declare @StartNumber int 
Declare @EndNumber int
Declare @No nvarchar(25)
Declare @StartCounter int
Declare @EndCounter int
Declare @Number varchar(15)

--Getting the letter
set @Series = substring(@StartingNumber, 1, 1)

--Getting the starting index of the starting and ending Number
set @StartIndex = patindex('%[1-9]%', @StartingNumber)
set @EndIndex = patindex('%[1-9]%', @EndingNumber)

--Getting the starting and ending number
set @StartNumber = substring(@StartingNumber, @StartIndex, 6)
set @EndNumber = substring(@EndingNumber, @EndIndex, 6)

--Converting number string to integer
set @StartCounter = Convert(int, @StartNumber)
set @EndCounter = Convert(int, @EndNumber)

while (@StartCounter <= @EndCounter)

   set @Number = CONVERT(varchar, @StartCounter)

   if @StartCounter >= 1 and @StartCounter < 10
      set @No = @Series + '0000' + @Number

   if @StartCounter >= 10 and @StartCounter < 100
      set @No= @Series + '000' + @Number

   if @StartCounter >= 100 and @StartCounter < 1000
      set @No= @Series + '00' + @Number

   if @StartCounter >= 1000 and @StartCounter < 10000
      set @No= @Series + '0' + @Number

   if @StartCounter >= 10000 and @StartCounter < 100000
      set @No= @Series + @Number

BEGIN
   Insert into TestingNumber(Number)
   Values(@No);

   set @StartCounter = @StartCounter + 1
END
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that reproduces your problem?https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
Maybe provide a sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should write `BEGIN` after `while`. Otherwise, it makes an infinite loop at your procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertNumbers] 
@StartingNumber nvarchar(25),
@EndingNumber nvarchar(25)
AS
Declare @StartIndex int 
Declare @EndIndex int 
Declare @Series varchar(5) 
Declare @StartNumber int 
Declare @EndNumber int
Declare @No nvarchar(25)
Declare @StartCounter int
Declare @EndCounter int
Declare @Number varchar(15)

--Getting the letter
set @Series = substring(@StartingNumber, 1, 1)

--Getting the starting index of the starting and ending Number
set @StartIndex = patindex('%[1-9]%', @StartingNumber)
set @EndIndex = patindex('%[1-9]%', @EndingNumber)

--Getting the starting and ending number
set @StartNumber = substring(@StartingNumber, @StartIndex, 6)
set @EndNumber = substring(@EndingNumber, @EndIndex, 6)

--Converting number string to integer
set @StartCounter = Convert(int, @StartNumber)
set @EndCounter = Convert(int, @EndNumber)

while (@StartCounter <= @EndCounter)
BEGIN
   set @Number = CONVERT(varchar, @StartCounter)

   if @StartCounter >= 1 and @StartCounter < 10
      set @No = @Series + '0000' + @Number

   if @StartCounter >= 10 and @StartCounter < 100
      set @No= @Series + '000' + @Number

   if @StartCounter >= 100 and @StartCounter < 1000
      set @No= @Series + '00' + @Number

   if @StartCounter >= 1000 and @StartCounter < 10000
      set @No= @Series + '0' + @Number

   if @StartCounter >= 10000 and @StartCounter < 100000
      set @No= @Series + @Number


   Insert into TestingNumber(Number)
   Values(@No);

   set @StartCounter = @StartCounter + 1
END
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works. I thought the conversion of @StartCounter to varchar  is creating infinite loop while incrementing. Is it a good way to solve such problems because i feel it is making very long procedure so it might affect the performance of the program. Can you share if there is any simple solutions for it?

Comment: You're welcome! You can change all @No seting lines with this single line `SET @No = @Series + RIGHT('00000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), @StartCounter), 5)`